# Using Dart to find the content of an H1 tag in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, dart, mobile-application

So basically I'm trying to teach myself mobile development using Dart and Flutter and currently, I am trying to have the mobile app connect to a website and take the text of the H1 tag and just display it in the console for now. Also, the H1 tag is being loaded through Javascript. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**If i right understand this is your answer:**

Furthering Seth's comment, you should be able to use the html library for this.

That should look something like this:
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

```
var document = parse(response.body);
var priceElement = document.getElementsByClassName("product_price_from");
// priceElement may have weird formatting (I see &nbsp;) so you might need to do some parsing
// here to solve that
```

for more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409611/flutter-fetch-certain-elements-of-a-html-page)